# Should I tell the potential company that my company is undertaking organization change after I tender my resignation?

Tags: interviewing

I have been with my current company for 10 months. 3 months ago, I tendered my resignation because of the company cultural difference and my supervisor's micromanagement (I have a 3 months notice period). Twenty(20) days after my resignation, the company announced a huge organizational restructure.

I'm going through some interviews recently, should I tell the potential companies that the company is having changes or just simply tell them that I'm not fit for the company culture?

Comment: Are you currently in the 3 month notice period?

Comment: There are plenty of plenty moving from those reasons, I did the same a few months ago. If everybody was happy on their current jobs, nobody would be in the job market. You are overthinking this.

Comment: If you didn't know about the changes at the time of resigning, using this as a reason for resigning would be a lie, wouldn't it?

Comment: So your reason would be the company is undergoing changes.  I don't know how those changes might effect me.  And for those reasons I resigned.

Comment: yes I'm still in the 3 months. Next Fri is the last day.

Comment: *Don't* say "I am not a fit" makes you sound like you are difficult to work with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any information on your present company is supposed to be confidential unless publicly released. And you don't want to give the impression of the guy who leaks confidential information.

Moreover, what does this info add to your evaluation, since you are not leaving the company because of the reorganization but because of the reasons you mention? As you probably know, the interview is meant for both sides to evaluate the fit of each other. I don't see how this detail can be positive for you.

Comment: I disagree slightly. A reorg can lead to many things, retrenchment being one of them.I've been through one where my role was dissolved, however I was offer another one in a different department. Very legitimate reason to mention to a recruiter

Comment: @Freewill, the OP is not searching another job because of the reorganization. So I see no point in disclosing this information.

Comment: I think OP is trying to ascertain whether mentioning the reorg (which so happened to be the case after OP tendered their resignation for another reason) is a better reason than the one that made them resign. My point is, the fact there is a reorg isn't "confidential" information ,in my opinion, as such unless OP goes into deeper details

Comment: @Freewill, confidentiality aside, to me "I am leaving the job because I don't fit in the organization" sounds way better than "I am leaving because of reorg". The first motivation shows him as capable of taking initiative, the second one sounds more like "I follow the flow".

Comment: @L.Dutch I disagree "I don't fit in" sends a negative message to any interviewer

Comment: @Neuromancer: Well, that depends on the reasons for not fitting in. I think most interviewers would ask about how someone "didn't fit in". There are good and bad reasons for not fitting...